# Chrome lighthouse score gives poor scores on different systems

Tags: audit, lighthouse

We are using chrome lighthouse extension for running tests on our pages and improves performances score. We have however a problem. On a MacBook Pro-2015, we get a 94 performance score and also 94 performance score in a Windows virtual machine running on the laptop. However on a 64-bit Windows laptop with an Intel Pentium n3540 CPU, we get below 50. Even demo pages found online that claim 90+ score will not go above 50 on this system.
Are there any specific requirements that the lighthouse has in order to run correctly? Or some special settings need to be done on the Windows system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lighthouse can be configured to run on most systems, nothing precludes it from running on windows (it should run on windows out of the box), but there will definitely be variation based on the system that it runs on un-throttled.  If you want a consistent bar to run against consider running against [WebPageTest](https://www.webpagetest.org/lighthouse).  Or play with their custom settings to get an audit that is exactly what you want that can be run consistently.

I think that running lighthouse on a computer with a chip that was [released 4 years](https://ark.intel.com/products/series/76756/Intel-Pentium-Processor-N-Series) ago will probably yield low results, as you are experiencing.  Which is probably an accurate depiction of how performant a website will be on that hardware.  This might be a case of WAI.

Are you running Lighthouse with simulated throttling, or with throttling off?  That can also increase variation.

Comment: Thank you for that site. I run it with simulated throttling. Without that, I would get 100 even on the worsed optimized page so I don't think you are supposed to do it without. But that site gives consistent results so I'll be using that as the final judge.